# Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 12, in <module> for error in authorisation: TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python

this is my first time coding on my own on python
i am having error in this

```
invalid = ''
authorisation = False
system_authorisation = (input("hi what is your name? "))
for user in system_authorisation:
  if system_authorisation == "ali":
    authorisation = True
    print ("welcome")
  elif system_authorisation != "ali":
    authorisation = False
  for error in authorisation:
    while authorisation == False:
      invalid = (input("invalid password try again- "))
      if invalid == "ali":
        print("welcome")
```

Comment: Can you edit your question?

Comment: i did now check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The bug lies in the second `for loop`.**

```
for error in authorisation:
```

You are trying to iterate over a boolean variable.

`authorisation` is a variable that contains `True` or `False`.

The object must be iterable, like a list for example:

```
for item in list:
```